# WSO2 roles & Permission Identity server for OAuth2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

**Q1:** What all are the permissions that we have provide a new user so that OAuth token can be generated?
**Q2:** For validating the OAuth2, what permission have to be given for a new user?
**Q3:** What is the scope of OAuth2 validation , if the User is under a new-tenant?
**Q4:** Why is it a blank-page, when I give Identity-permission for User on OAuth2/Inbound authentication Configuration..!

***WSO2 IS v 5.2.0***

Comment: can please explain q3 and q4 a bit more. I will update the answer for them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: What all are the permissions that we have to provide a new user so that OAuth token can be generated?

> I don't think you need any permission at all.

Q2: For validating the OAuth2, what permission have to be given for a new user?

> In order to call the token validation the service, the user calling
>   the service should have
>   **/permission/admin/manage/identity/applicationmgt/view** permission

Comment: there are permission given depending on the user being an admin or not.. Hope we can use the admin creds to generate OAuth2 tokens for the underlying users..